# jQuery Fullscreen Background Image

Tags: jquery, image, background, fullscreen, slideshow

I need help with a jQuery plugin which scales images into fullscreen and still allows a user to put contents under it. For example:

[www.burton.com](http://www.burton.com/)

The site above has a fullscreen image and also contents under it. Can someone show me how to do this?

I've tried different jQuery Image slideshow plugins but am still failing to accomplish it. I'll be using it for my school project.

Answer (score 2):

Try this > [MaxImage 2.0 - jQuery Fullscreen Background Slideshow Plugin](http://jquery-plugins.net/maximage-2-0-jquery-fullscreen-background-slideshow-plugin#)