# Do not move background image on Window resize, keep it static

Tags: html, css

When I resize my window the background image also moves and gets resized, I dont want it to get resize, i want it to remain static. I am really confused how to keep my background static.
If I set the width in pixels, then it remains static but that wont be good option as depending on different screen sizes

```
body {
    background-color: #000000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

#container {
    background: url("url") no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The code is like:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try this?

```
#container {
    background: url("url");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: the image gets aligned to right , but yes the static thing gets solved

Comment: hi did you try instead of `background-position:fixed;` try this `background-position:center top;`

Comment: There is no `fixed` value for background-position.

Comment: No such thing as a "background-position: fixed;"

Answer (score 1):

Try this code -

```
#container {
    background: transparent url("url") 0 0 no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: the image gets aligned to right now, but yes the static thing gets solved

Comment: it does not actually, I knew this property but using this, the whole alignment gets changed

Comment: You may even use javascript/jquery to make your background as full screen. Refer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089855/jquery-fullscreen-background-image

Answer (score 0):

If you set the image to be `width:100%` then the image will resize with the screen. If you want it to just sit on the top center without scaling then you can use `position:fixed`, explicit `width` and then position it correctly.

```
#container {
    background:url("url") no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
    background-position:fixed;
    position:fixed;
    width:500px; /* width of image */
    height:auto;
    top:0;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-250px; /* -1/2 width */
}
```